# How to copy a std::string except for its first character?

Tags: c++, string

I have to copy `originalString` to `newString` except for the first character (`~`). The content of `originalString` should not be changed.

```
std::string originalString("~myOriginalString");
std::string newString;
…
// expected result: newString is "myOriginalString", originalString is unmodified.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, this sort of operation can be performed with iterators:

```
string newString(originalString.begin()+1, originalString.end());
```

Comment: +1 for proposing the most generic solution.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Well, the most generic solution would use `std::begin`/`std::end` and `boost::next` (depending on the type of flexibility needed).

Comment: True, from an internal point of view.  But it means that you'd need C++11, which many of us can't use yet in production.

Comment: does that do internally exactly what substr() would do? is that iterator solution faster perhaps?

Answer (score 6):

Simply using [`std::string::substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr):

```
string newString(originalString.substr(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` has a method, `substr()`, which does just this. Look it up.

Answer (score 0):

Use [substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) string member function:

```
 newString = originalString.substr(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is std::string, you can just do the following:

```
newString = originalString;
newString.replace(0, 1, "");
```

alternatively there is also a method called `erase`:

```
newString = originalString;
newString.erase(0, 1);
```

Basically this replaces the part beginning at the 0th character with length 1 by the empty string. The second method doesn't replace, but directly erases this part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use c-tor for that:

`string newString(originalString, 1);`